# Entering local date on Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, keyboard-shortcuts, date

If I use the shortcut <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd> the date that is pasted is the server date. I have changed the settings so my Time zone is selected to my local time.

Shouldn't my local time get pasted as opposed to the server time?

Do I need to configure elsewhere or is this feature not implemented the way I am expecting it to behave?

Comment: Is there any difference with the updated shortcut Ctrl+Shift+;?

Comment: @MaQleod: No, that only prints the time. I want the date. Being in timezone which is around 12 hours ahead with server time, for earlier part of the day here, I get a date that is 1 day behind.

Answer (score 3):

I tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd> and it shows the local date (and time with  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd>) so the issue appears to be fixed.